# I would like to ask ONLY about a permission to a microphone for MediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}) and hide red dot in tab

Tags: javascript, browser, permissions, stream, mediastream

Hi I have a problem with permission to userMedia API.

I would like to call getUserMedia but before I have to ask about a permission to the microphone.

Is it possible to only asks about the permission to the microphone without triggering red dot in a tab which means start recording.

I would like to just ask using Javascript about a permission to the microphone without starting recording anything in MediaStream class.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply ask for the `"microphone"` permission currently.

However you can workaround around this issue and stop all tracks from the resulting media stream just after the call to hide the red dot.

```js
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
// Stop recording microphone (and hide red dot).
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
```